# Unit Test Async WebAPI 2 Get Request

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api, async-await

I am trying to test my web api methods that are using async and they never return a result.

Here is the control method:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("{id}")]
[ResponseType(typeof(IEmployee))]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get(string id)
{
    try
    {
        IEmployee result = await _repoEmployee.GetEmployeeAsync(id);

        return Ok(result);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        logit.Error($@"An error occurred while trying to get Employee for Employee number ""{id}"".", ex);
        throw;
    }
}
```

Here is the test using NUnit:

```
[TestCase("0677")]
public async Task EmployeeController_Get_GiveValidEmpID_Success(string employeeNumber)
{
    Setup();

    // Act
    IHttpActionResult getResult = await _controller.Get(employeeNumber);

    var contentResult = getResult as NegotiatedContentResult<IEmployee>;

    // Assert
    Assert.IsNotNull(contentResult);
    Assert.AreEqual(HttpStatusCode.Accepted, contentResult.StatusCode);
    Assert.IsNotNull(contentResult.Content);
    Assert.AreEqual(employeeNumber, contentResult.Content.Person.EmployeeNumber);
}
```

If I debug the Get method the correct results appear in the result variable but when it gets back to the test method the getResult is nothing.

Where am I going wrong and how can I fix it in order to test the results?

Thanks!

Comment: Is `getResult` null or is `contentResult` null?

Comment: contentResult is null.  I can't get anything from the immediate window for getResult.

Comment: So `contentResult` is null because `getResult` is not of type `NegotiatedContentResult<IEmployee>`

Comment: Ahhh that makes sense.  I will let you know if that works.

Comment: Try `OkNegotiatedContentResult<IEmployee>` instead.

Comment: That's it.  Thanks you!  I think I need to brush up on web api 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `getResult` is not of type `NegotiatedContentResult<IEmployee>` the cast results in a null value for `contentResult`. Instead, you probably want to cast to `OkNegotiatedContentResult<IEmployee>`:

```
var contentResult = getResult as OkNegotiatedContentResult<IEmployee>;
```